# Change data type using an interface

Tags: javascript, typescript, types

I have an object typed with a variable of typeString, which collects the value of a variable of type any.

The problem is that this variable is a number and when it is collected it is still of type number.

Is there any way to adapt the type of data collected to the typing of the interface?

This is the process:

```
let dataID: any = 4

interface Test {
  testID: string
}

let dataObj: Test = {
  testID: dataID
}

console.log(typeof dataObj.testID) // number
```

This is what I need:

```
console.log(typeof dataObj.testID) // string
```

Answer (score 1):

You can parse type to string while you init your object.

```
let dataObj: Test = {
  testID: dataID.toString()
}
```

Comment: That will fail when `dataID` is `null` or `undefined`. There is no guarantee at type level that it wouldn't, since it's typed as `any`.